# MySQL select of everything before @

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select out the part of an email address column before `@`. So if a row is `somebody@somewhere.com`, how do I select `somebody` out of each row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select substring_index('somebody@somewhere.com', '@', 1);
```

doc -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1) AS emailname FROM table;
```